# How to embed YouTube/Vimeo videos responsively full width in the background

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, vimeo

I have following two section that I want to display one after another.

In first section I am trying to set a 100% by 100% Vimeo video as background.

I have tried some combinations of absolute and relative position settings but either I lost full width/height of the video or the second section superimpose on the first one.

What I want is something similar to this:

http://template.ridianur.com/bahe/youtube-background/index.html

```
<section id='bg-video'>
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/149224063?autoplay=1&color=ff0179&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="780" height="438" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>


<section>
    <div class="box">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</section>
enter code here
```

The relevant portion of the stylesheet I currently have is:

```
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

also if I use below stylesheet

```
#bg-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

#bg-video iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Full width is displayed:

[image: snapshot of image displayed]

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code ?

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/q6qcp7u3/)**

[ref.](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-embed-youtubevimeo-videos-responsively/)

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
section iframe,
section object,
section embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/149224063?autoplay=1&color=ff0179&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

</section>
```

Comment: can you please explain what are you trying to do here? because i want to understand it as well. Thanx